# check library version netcdf linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netcdf

how do I determine which version of the netcdf library is installed in my system? Is there a command line? I tried to search "netcdf" and I find a bunch of files but I can't determine the version number.
Is there a command to check the version of anything installed?

I am on ubuntu

Answer (score 20, accepted):

netCDF provides the `nc-config` command line tool for this purpose.

To print the version.

```
nc-config --version
```

To print more information on the netCDF build you have:

```
nc-config --all
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the package is installed, you can use the following command:

```
dpkg-query --list netcdf
```

Personally I don't have netcdf installed, but you will have an output like this:

```
$ dpkg-query --list netbase
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  netbase        5.3          all          Basic TCP/IP networking system
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding two solutions that are more OS-agnostic than `dpkg-query` (which doesn't work on, e.g. Mac OS X).  First, often the version information is included in the path where the package is installed, and so you can use `which` to display it:

```
$ which ncdump
/usr/local/netcdf-4.2_optimized/bin/ncdump
```

Second, many docstrings also include the version number, so just printing them out will do the trick.  For example, print the usage instructions of `ncdump` by calling it with with no arguments:

```
$ ncdump
ncdump [-c|-h] [-v ...] [[-b|-f] [c|f]] [-l len] [-n name] [-p n[,n]] [-k] [-x] [-s] [-t|-i] [-g ...] [-w] file
       [-c]             Coordinate variable data and header information
       ...
       file             Name of netCDF file
netcdf library version 4.2 of May 23 2012 12:14:03 $
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a few lines of C:

```
#include <netcdf.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("I am NetCDF version %s\n", nc_inq_libvers());
}
```

On my laptop that reports:

```
I am NetCDF version 4.1.3 of Feb 24 2014 21:05:37 $
```